# Any Java hash tree implementations?

Tags: java, hashtree

I want to implement an algorithm that needs to use a hash tree. What are some good, easy-to-understand Java hash tree implementations? Are there books, websites or PDFs on the Internet that give a good explanation on how a hash tree works and how I could implement it?

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/projects/tigertree/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there's a Java implementation of hash tree here:

http://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jorphan/collections/HashTree.html

There's an explanation here:

http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=java%20hash%20tree&source=web&cd=17&ved=0CFUQFjAGOAo&url=http%3A%2F%2Fciteseerx.ist.psu.edu%2Fviewdoc%2Fdownload%3Fdoi%3D10.1.1.21.6279%26rep%3Drep1%26type%3Dpdf&ei=tQijTrvMIOTb0QHRxIyBBQ&usg=AFQjCNGTjFqUeqzT8ldQQComx24SF4Z0ow

Google is your friend.